New Relic APM not connecting to postgres, redis, using NestJS
I installed New Relic APM on my NestJS application running in ECS Fargate.
I followed all the guides to setup for nodejs, and installed the agent on Fargate using the CLI.
Locally and in a deployed environment, I am able to see my requests come through, however, I do not see postgres and redis on the service map, or in the tracing. I have enabled all the correct configurations both locally and on the platform override. I should be getting these traces.
I have tried different combinations of configurations without any luck, New Relic runs fine, but I cannot get the tracing.
I compared to other projects not using NestJS (express, koa, django) and the setup is the exact same (install agent, set config, run application), and I get all the distributed tracing right away.
I'm only having this issue with nestjs, anyone have any thoughts? I really would like to use new relic because I use it for all my other applications and find it very user friendly.
